# JavaScript code variable order declaration confusion

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain the below code snippet in javascript

```
this.config.min = undefined != configuration.min ? configuration.min : 0;
```

Comment: Its a ternary condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) condition. Its like:

```
if (configuration.min != undefined)
{
    this.config.min = configuration.min;
}
else
{
    this.config.min = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan nice, glad to help.

Comment: :min: undefined != min ? min : 0,

does the above line also means the same as u explained earlier